# how can i access td class via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

how can i access my td class via jquery
here is HTML code

```
<td class="selectable" id="shoes-<?= $color->id ?>" ></td>

  <td><a href="?shoes=<?php  echo $color->id; ?>" title="Select"
     <?php if($shoes==$order->shoes){ ?> class="selected"<?php } ?>>
```

Here is jQuery Code

```
$('td.selectable a').click(function() {


    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    var data = $parent.attr('id').split('-');
    var type = data[0];
    var typeId = data[1];
```

if i alert (type); i receive nothing
could you help

now i got it solved but second part still problem
I am trying to switch my class  it should show up while clicking on a link here is the html code

```
<td class="selectable" id="person-<?= $person->id ?>">
     <a href="?person=<?php  echo $person->id; ?>" title="Selecteren"
 if($person==$order->person){ ?> class="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $person->name;?></a></td>
```

it works with span class and div class but with  a class=selected does not work

```
$('#personAmount td.selectable  a').click(function() {
       var $parent = $(this).parent()
        var data = $parent.attr('id').split('-');
        var type = data[0];
        var typeId = data[1];


switch(type){
            case 'person':
            $(this).prepend('<a class="selected"></a>');

            break;
            case 'color':
            $(this).prepend('<div class="checked"></div>');

            break;
            default:
            $parent.prepend('<span class="checked"></span>');

        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do with inserting those elements in the <a>. In the first case of the switch, you are inserting an `<a>` inside the current '<a>'.

Comment: i am trying to add an image which is behind the class=selected infront of mine td which has a also hope it is a bit clear with div and span i can add this image in my list only with class selected it does not show up. i just removed the a now i have it like this $(this).prepend('<class="selected">'); still no success

Answer (score 4):

```
$('td a').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.selectable').attr('id');
    var d = id.split('-');
    var item_type = d[0];
    var type_id = d[1];
    alert(type_id);
    alert(item_type);
});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/Kmrgn/)

Comment: @mary does this not do what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `<td>` that includes the `<a>` doesn't have `id` and `class` attributes. The `click` event won't be bound to that `<a>`

Comment: I think the issue is that the `<td>` with `class="selectable"` doesn't include an `<a>`

Comment: you are right i got it now it works thanks but my type includes a switch function it does not show up here is the code

Comment: you are right i got it now it works thanks but my type includes a switch function also i got the div class and span class right but only in case person it does't show up here is the code switch(type){
   case 'person':
   $parent.prepend('<class="selected">');
   
   break;
   case 'color':
   $(this).prepend('<div class="checked"></div>');
      break;
   default:
   $parent.prepend('<span class="checked"></span>');
   
  }

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code of your previous comment there. It's hard to read it here.

Comment: @Mary Please edit **your question**, and not this answer. Scroll up and click "edit" under your original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().prev();
```

You've got a hierarchy like this:

```
<td class="selectable"></td>
<td>
    <a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your current HTML:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VwFvD/)**

```
$('td.selectable + td a').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent().prev();
    var data = $parent.attr('id').split('-');
    var type = data[0];
    var typeId = data[1];
    alert(type);
});
```

Comment: look i have the same stracture for li $(li.selectable a).click(function) it works why not with table i don't know <li class="selectable" id="color-<?= $color->id ?>"> <a href="?color=<?php echo ($color->id); ?>" title="Selecteer"> <?php if($color == $order->color){?><div class="checked"></div><?php }?>

Comment: @mary: As others have said, your `<a>` element is NOT within your `<td class="selectable">` element.